# how call filter 'h' in mason?

Tags: perl, filter, mason

As doc says I may apply H filter by next code `<% $message_body | h %>`

But calling filter is not covered when I inside <%perl> tag.

Yes, doc says that I can call `$m->filter(...`, but this produce next error:

```
Error during compilation of /.../input: 
Bareword found where operator expected at /.../input line 42, near "$.H" (Missing operator before H?)
```

My perl code is:

```
$m->filter( $.H, "$value" );
```

My work around is:

```
</%perl>
<% $value | h%>
<%perl>
```

But this is ugly. Please correct me, what I did wrong at `$m->filter( $.H, "$value" );`

Comment: What is `$.H` supposed to represent? `$.` is a variable in Perl that represents the current line number for the last filehandle that was accessed.

Comment: `use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities ); encode_entities($value)`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen $.H - link to filter. See. http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.23/lib/Mason/Manual/Filters.pod#Manual_invocation I also do not understand how it works.

Comment: @ikegami: I want to use native feature for code integrity.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I'm using Mason and `print $m->filter( $.H, "$value" );` works as expected .. can we see a little more code? how do you use the value returned?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
print $m->apply_escapes($value, 'h');
```